# Python Generate some instances using predefined class

Tags: python, class, instance, generate

Using class `NickNames`, needed to generate some number of instances using this class where `id` should be - increment, `nicks` - should be randomly picked from the list and `timestamp` should take current timestamp and store the output into list

Curently i am getting this type of output `[<__main__.NickNames object at 0x00000213547E9AC8>, <__main__.NickNames object at 0x00000213548409E8>]`
instead of desired 
`1, crown, 119121392391293 (timestamp)`
`2, makes, 119121392391298 (timestamp)`
Please help.

Here`s the code i`m using

```
import random
import calendar
import time

nicknames = ['child', 'makes', 'override', 'even', 'eleven', 'householder', 'snowball', 'cure', 'crown']

class NickNames:
  def __init__(self, id, nicks, timestamp):
    self.id = id
    self.nicks = nicks
    self.timestamp = timestamp

res = []

for i in range(2):
    res.append(NickNames(uuid.uuid1(), random.choice(nicknames), calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())))

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the res.append replace uuid.uuid1() by (i + 1).
Replace print(res) by:

for obj in res:
    print(obj.id, obj.nicks, obj.timestamp)